# Getting Facebook status messages of a page I own

Tags: php, javascript, xml, json, facebook

Say I have a page on Facebook and updating its status and posting on its wall.
What I want is getting that data in json or xml format and use it on my own web page.

All the api docs I've read so far requires an access token, which I shouldn't need.

Twitter has a rest api like `http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/twitter_username.json?count=10`, which returns the data in json format. I need something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Facebook graph API calls require an access token, including the page feed you seek.  You can get the feed in json format like: https://graph.facebook.com/pageIdOrName/feed or https://graph.facebook.com/pageIdOrName/statuses but you will need to append an access_token querystring parameter.   You can test this with the [Facebook Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and you could even use that access_token if you don't want to create an application.